# marginal effects in R not producing std. error or confidence interval for first variable value

Tags: r, marginal-effects, fixest, r-marginaleffects

I am trying to calculate the average prediction for a regression that includes an interaction term. I am using the avg_prediction command from the marginal_effects package to do this. However, when I run the command with both variables included in the interaction term (voter_party.y * white.x), I always get NA values for the standard errors for the first value of voter_party.y.

Strangely, when I run the avg_predictions command with just one variable (such as white.x or voter_party.y), there is no issue. It seems like the interaction term is causing the problem.

When I remove the fixed effect the std. errors reappear.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this issue?

```
florida_zip_fe<-feols(race_change~voter_party.y*white.x|voter_zip.y+voter_gender.x,
                                   data=analysis_fl2)



me_fl<-marginaleffects:: avg_predictions(florida_zip_fe,variables=c("voter_party.y","white.x"),
                                         type="response")
```

```
structure(list(voter_id_name = c("124053578JOHN", "119587396ANNE", 
"114746362EARL", "111052056SETH", "120579075CATHERINE", "112125650E"
), voter_party.y = c("independent", "republican", "republican", 
"republican", "democrat", "independent"), white.x = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), voter_zip.y = structure(c(611L, 58L, 
341L, 791L, 609L, 470L), levels = c("", "*", "22897", "30065", 
"30803", "32000", "32003", "32007", "32008", "32009", "32011", 
"32024", "32025", "32033", "32034", "32038", "32040", "32041", 
"32043", "32044", "32046", "32052", "32053", "32054", "32055", 
"32058", "32059", "32060", "32061", "32062", "32063", "32064", 
"32065", "32066", "32068", "32071", "32073", "32080", "32081", 
"32082", "32083", "32084", "32086", "32087", "32091", "32092", 
"32094", "32095", "32096", "32097", "32102", "32110", "32112", 
"32113", "32114", "32117", "32118", "32119", "32124", "32127", 
"32128", "32129", "32130", "32131", "32132", "32133", "32134", 
"32136", "32137", "32139", "32140", "32141", "32145", "32147", 
"32148", "32159", "32162", "32163", "32164", "32168", "32169", 
"32174", "32176", "32177", "32179", "32180", "32181", "32182", 
"32185", "32187", "32189", "32190", "32193", "32195", "32202", 
"32204", "32205", "32206", "32207", "32208", "32209", "32210", 
"32211", "32212", "32215", "32216", "32217", "32218", "32219", 
"32220", "32221", "32222", "32223", "32224", "32225", "32226", 
"32227", "32228", "32233", "32234", "32244", "32246", "32250", 
"32254", "32256", "32257", "32258", "32259", "32266", "32277", 
"32301", "32303", "32304", "32305", "32306", "32307", "32308", 
"32309", "32310", "32311", "32312", "32313", "32317", "32320", 
"32321", "32322", "32323", "32324", "32326", "32327", "32328", 
"32330", "32331", "32332", "32333", "32334", "32335", "32336", 
"32337", "32340", "32343", "32344", "32345", "32346", "32347", 
"32348", "32350", "32351", "32352", "32355", "32356", "32357", 
"32358", "32359", "32360", "32361", "32401", "32403", "32404", 
"32405", "32407", "32408", "32409", "32413", "32420", "32421", 
"32423", "32424", "32425", "32426", "32427", "32428", "32430", 
"32431", "32433", "32435", "32437", "32438", "32439", "32440", 
"32442", "32443", "32444", "32445", "32446", "32448", "32449", 
"32455", "32456", "32459", "32460", "32461", "32462", "32463", 
"32464", "32465", "32466", "32501", "32502", "32503", "32504", 
"32505", "32506", "32507", "32508", "32511", "32512", "32514", 
"32526", "32531", "32533", "32534", "32535", "32536", "32537", 
"32538", "32539", "32541", "32542", "32544", "32547", "32548", 
"32550", "32561", "32563", "32564", "32565", "32566", "32567", 
"32568", "32569", "32570", "32571", "32577", "32578", "32579", 
"32580", "32583", "32601", "32603", "32605", "32606", "32607", 
"32608", "32609", "32611", "32612", "32615", "32616", "32617", 
"32618", "32619", "32621", "32622", "32625", "32626", "32628", 
"32630", "32631", "32633", "32639", "32640", "32641", "32643", 
"32648", "32653", "32654", "32656", "32658", "32664", "32666", 
"32667", "32668", "32669", "32680", "32683", "32686", "32692", 
"32693", "32694", "32696", "32697", "32701", "32702", "32703", 
"32704", "32707", "32708", "32709", "32710", "32712", "32713", 
"32714", "32720", "32723", "32724", "32725", "32726", "32730", 
"32732", "32735", "32736", "32738", "32744", "32746", "32750", 
"32751", "32754", "32757", "32759", "32763", "32764", "32765", 
"32766", "32767", "32768", "32771", "32773", "32776", "32778", 
"32779", "32780", "32784", "32789", "32790", "32792", "32796", 
"32798", "32800", "32801", "32802", "32803", "32804", "32805", 
"32806", "32807", "32808", "32809", "32810", "32811", "32812", 
"32814", "32815", "32816", "32817", "32818", "32819", "32820", 
"32821", "32822", "32823", "32824", "32825", "32826", "32827", 
"32828", "32829", "32830", "32831", "32832", "32833", "32835", 
"32836", "32837", "32839", "32852", "32856", "32859", "32861", 
"32868", "32869", "32877", "32878", "32896", "32897", "32901", 
"32903", "32904", "32905", "32907", "32908", "32909", "32920", 
"32922", "32925", "32926", "32927", "32931", "32934", "32935", 
"32937", "32940", "32948", "32949", "32950", "32951", "32952", 
"32953", "32955", "32958", "32960", "32961", "32962", "32963", 
"32966", "32967", "32968", "32976", "33001", "33004", "33008", 
"33009", "33010", "33012", "33013", "33014", "33015", "33016", 
"33018", "33019", "33020", "33021", "33022", "33023", "33024", 
"33025", "33026", "33027", "33028", "33029", "33030", "33031", 
"33032", "33033", "33034", "33035", "33036", "33037", "33039", 
"33040", "33042", "33043", "33044", "33046", "33050", "33051", 
"33054", "33055", "33056", "33060", "33062", "33063", "33064", 
"33065", "33066", "33067", "33068", "33069", "33070", "33071", 
"33072", "33073", "33075", "33076", "33078", "33080", "33081", 
"33082", "33088", "33089", "33097", "33101", "33109", "33119", 
"33122", "33124", "33125", "33126", "33127", "33128", "33129", 
"33130", "33131", "33132", "33133", "33134", "33135", "33136", 
"33137", "33138", "33139", "33140", "33141", "33142", "33143", 
"33144", "33145", "33146", "33147", "33149", "33150", "33152", 
"33154", "33155", "33156", "33157", "33158", "33160", "33161", 
"33162", "33165", "33166", "33167", "33168", "33169", "33170", 
"33172", "33173", "33174", "33175", "33176", "33177", "33178", 
"33179", "33180", "33181", "33182", "33183", "33184", "33185", 
"33186", "33187", "33189", "33190", "33193", "33194", "33196", 
"33216", "33224", "33301", "33304", "33305", "33306", "33307", 
"33308", "33309", "33311", "33312", "33313", "33314", "33315", 
"33316", "33317", "33319", "33321", "33322", "33323", "33324", 
"33325", "33326", "33327", "33328", "33329", "33330", "33331", 
"33332", "33334", "33351", "33360", "33362", "33363", "33365", 
"33394", "33401", "33402", "33403", "33404", "33405", "33406", 
"33407", "33408", "33409", "33410", "33411", "33412", "33413", 
"33414", "33415", "33417", "33418", "33426", "33428", "33430", 
"33431", "33432", "33433", "33434", "33435", "33436", "33437", 
"33438", "33439", "33440", "33441", "33442", "33444", "33445", 
"33446", "33449", "33455", "33458", "33459", "33460", "33461", 
"33462", "33463", "33467", "33468", "33469", "33470", "33471", 
"33472", "33473", "33476", "33477", "33478", "33479", "33480", 
"33481", "33483", "33484", "33486", "33487", "33488", "33493", 
"33496", "33498", "33503", "33508", "33510", "33511", "33513", 
"33514", "33521", "33523", "33524", "33525", "33527", "33530", 
"33534", "33537", "33538", "33539", "33540", "33541", "33542", 
"33543", "33544", "33545", "33547", "33548", "33549", "33550", 
"33556", "33558", "33559", "33563", "33565", "33566", "33567", 
"33569", "33570", "33572", "33573", "33574", "33576", "33578", 
"33579", "33584", "33585", "33586", "33592", "33593", "33594", 
"33595", "33596", "33597", "33598", "33601", "33602", "33603", 
"33604", "33605", "33606", "33607", "33609", "33610", "33611", 
"33612", "33613", "33614", "33615", "33616", "33617", "33618", 
"33619", "33620", "33621", "33624", "33625", "33626", "33629", 
"33630", "33632", "33634", "33635", "33637", "33639", "33644", 
"33647", "33668", "33680", "33683", "33686", "33688", "33698", 
"33701", "33702", "33703", "33704", "33705", "33706", "33707", 
"33708", "33709", "33710", "33711", "33712", "33713", "33714", 
"33715", "33716", "33730", "33743", "33744", "33755", "33756", 
"33758", "33759", "33760", "33761", "33762", "33763", "33764", 
"33765", "33767", "33770", "33771", "33772", "33773", "33774", 
"33776", "33777", "33778", "33781", "33782", "33785", "33786", 
"33801", "33802", "33803", "33804", "33805", "33806", "33807", 
"33808", "33809", "33810", "33811", "33812", "33813", "33814", 
"33815", "33816", "33818", "33819", "33820", "33821", "33823", 
"33825", "33826", "33827", "33830", "33831", "33832", "33833", 
"33834", "33835", "33836", "33837", "33838", "33839", "33840", 
"33841", "33843", "33844", "33845", "33846", "33847", "33848", 
"33849", "33850", "33851", "33852", "33853", "33854", "33855", 
"33856", "33857", "33858", "33859", "33860", "33861", "33863", 
"33865", "33867", "33868", "33869", "33870", "33872", "33873", 
"33875", "33876", "33877", "33878", "33879", "33880", "33881", 
"33882", "33883", "33884", "33885", "33887", "33888", "33889", 
"33890", "33891", "33892", "33893", "33894", "33895", "33896", 
"33897", "33898", "33901", "33903", "33904", "33905", "33907", 
"33908", "33909", "33912", "33913", "33914", "33916", "33917", 
"33919", "33920", "33921", "33922", "33924", "33928", "33930", 
"33931", "33932", "33935", "33936", "33937", "33943", "33944", 
"33946", "33947", "33948", "33950", "33952", "33953", "33954", 
"33955", "33956", "33957", "33959", "33960", "33965", "33966", 
"33967", "33971", "33972", "33973", "33974", "33975", "33976", 
"33980", "33981", "33982", "33983", "33990", "33991", "33993", 
"34102", "34103", "34104", "34105", "34108", "34109", "34110", 
"34112", "34113", "34114", "34116", "34117", "34119", "34120", 
"34134", "34135", "34137", "34138", "34139", "34140", "34141", 
"34142", "34145", "34201", "34202", "34203", "34205", "34207", 
"34208", "34209", "34210", "34211", "34212", "34215", "34216", 
"34217", "34219", "34221", "34222", "34223", "34224", "34228", 
"34229", "34231", "34232", "34233", "34234", "34235", "34236", 
"34237", "34238", "34239", "34240", "34241", "34242", "34243", 
"34250", "34251", "34266", "34269", "34272", "34275", "34285", 
"34286", "34287", "34288", "34289", "34291", "34292", "34293", 
"34420", "34428", "34429", "34430", "34431", "34432", "34433", 
"34434", "34436", "34442", "34445", "34446", "34448", "34449", 
"34450", "34452", "34453", "34461", "34465", "34470", "34471", 
"34472", "34473", "34474", "34475", "34476", "34479", "34480", 
"34481", "34482", "34484", "34488", "34491", "34498", "34579", 
"34601", "34602", "34604", "34606", "34607", "34608", "34609", 
"34610", "34613", "34614", "34637", "34638", "34639", "34652", 
"34653", "34654", "34655", "34656", "34659", "34660", "34661", 
"34667", "34668", "34669", "34673", "34677", "34679", "34680", 
"34681", "34683", "34684", "34685", "34688", "34689", "34690", 
"34691", "34695", "34698", "34705", "34711", "34714", "34715", 
"34729", "34731", "34734", "34736", "34737", "34739", "34740", 
"34741", "34743", "34744", "34745", "34746", "34747", "34748", 
"34749", "34750", "34753", "34755", "34756", "34758", "34759", 
"34760", "34761", "34762", "34764", "34769", "34771", "34772", 
"34773", "34778", "34785", "34786", "34787", "34788", "34789", 
"34794", "34797", "34884", "34945", "34946", "34947", "34949", 
"34950", "34951", "34952", "34953", "34956", "34957", "34972", 
"34974", "34981", "34982", "34983", "34984", "34986", "34987", 
"34988", "34990", "34994", "34996", "34997", "35759", "36389", 
"36759", "38330", "38337", "38801", "38803", "38813", "38844", 
"38850", "38881", "99999"), class = "factor"), voter_gender.x = c("M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F"), race_change = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), zip_change = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), party_change = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), add_change = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), change_year = structure(c(17939, 17939, 15859, 17295, 17939, 
16108), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x13a80b0e0>)
```

Comment: Which messages do you get when running `feols`?

Comment: sorry - ```me_fl<-marginaleffects:: avg_predictions(florida_zip_fe,variables=c("voter_party.y","white.x"),
                                         type="response")``` ends up producing a prediction for "Democrat" with NA std. errors

Comment: Hi, I am the `marginaleffects` maintainer. I cannot replicate the problem that you describe using the example data or different datasets. If you send me your full dataset by email I'll try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry, how do I send a private message - can you send me your email?

Comment: @sd3184 Sorry I missed this message. I am the `marginaleffects` package maintainer. My email is on the CRAN page and on my personal website.